# How to show user that swipe is possible on main page

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a few slides on main page but for user it's not clear that another views are available. I would like to show a demo that it's possible to swipe left by showing an piece of next slide. I just made next slide show, but it's not smooth.

```
$scope.nextSlide();
setTimeout($scope.prevSlide(), 1500);
```

How do i do swipe demo?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use an animated gif that shows the user the functionality. There are a lot of virtual tours like [Intro](http://introjs.com/) that also could help.